# Extend existing event

Tags: acumatica

I need to perform more action after the existing action is performed. For example, After Distribution > Sales Orders > Shipment > Action > Confirm Shipment, I need to populate all tracking numbers into another text box.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing here in my opinion would be to override the logic of the stock method.  That will allow you to add your needed code without touching the base method as well as you being able to validate information before and after the base method is called.

In the case of your example, "Confirm Shipment" action ultimately executes the method "ConfirmShipment" which is defined as below:

```
public virtual void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder)
{
.....
}
```

In order to customize the logic in here you have a few options.

- Create an override  method (added to the method queue, base called first then all 'override' methods)
- Create an  method that calls the stock one first, then your code. - this will in essence "replace" the stock logic but allow you to still call the base method.  in doing this, you can run some checks before calling the base.

To do the second you would do the following

Create first the delegate in your code:

```
public delegate void ConfirmShipmentDelegate(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder)
```

Then define your override method:

```
[PXOverride]
public virtual void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder, ConfirmShipmentDelegate baseMethod = null)
{
    // Call our base method first if it exists
    if (baseMethod != null) 
    {
        baseMethod(docgraph,shiporder);
    }
    // Do my stuff here
}
```

Couple items to note here.

- The definition has a third param to our delegate, this allows us to call the stock method and then do further work.  It also tells the Acumatica framework our method should take priority over the stock method.
- The stock method is called from the baseMethod call in the actual code.

Creating the extension this way allows for upgrades to occur without you having to totally redefine your method every time.

The second method would be just be an override of the stockcode.  That is done with the following syntax

```
[PXOverride]
public virtual void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder)
{}
```

When taking this approach, the stock method is first called, then your override method is called.

both of these would be handled in a graph extension defined as:

```
public class SOShipmentEntryExt  : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
```

Before attempting either, I would look at the articles in the Wiki on PXOverride as they give further examples/situations for these